# Is fortran-like print in python possible?

Tags: python, fortran

is it possible some way to "print" in python in a fortran like way like this?

```
1     4.5656
2    24.0900
3   698.2300
4    -3.5000
```

So the decimal points is always in the same column, and we get always 3 or n decimal numbers?

Thanks

Comment: and just last question,if I have to print 1000 lines and I have three floats on each, how can I do that for: 10spaces,f1 formatted,5spaces,f2 formatted,5spaces,f3 formatted

where fi formatted is%11.4f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> '%11.4f' % -3.5
'    -3.5000'
```

or the new style formatting:

```
>>> '{:11.4f}'.format(-3.5)
'    -3.5000'
```

more about [format specifiers in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: hi thanks! and last thign, let's say i have three floats f1, f2, f3, how can I print them? I tried '%11.4f' % f1,f2,f3 but nothing

Comment: @werner: use `'%11.4f %11.4f %11.4f' % (f1,f2,f3)`

Answer (score 5):

You could also take a look at the `fortranformat` library on PyPI or the [project page](https://bitbucket.org/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat/) if you wanted to fully recreate FORTRAN text IO.

If you have any questions, send me an email (I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in [(3, 4.534), (3, 15.234325), (10,341.11)]:
...     print "%5i %8.4f" % i
... 
    3   4.5340
    3  15.2343
   10 341.1100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "%10.3f" % f
```

will right align the number `f` (as an aside: `%-10.3f` would be left-aligned). The string will be right-aligned to 10 characters (it doesn't work any more with > 10 characters) and exactly 3 decimal digits. So:

```
f = 698.230 # <-- 7 characters when printed with %10.3f
print "%10.3f" % f # <-- will print "   698.2300" (two spaces)
```

As a test for your example set do the following:

```
print "\n".join(map(lambda f: "%10.3f" % f, [4.5656, 24.09, 698.23, -3.5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.rjust(), this way:

```
a = 4.5656
b = 24.0900
c = 698.2300
d = -3.5000

a = "%.4f" % a
b = "%.4f" % b
c = "%.4f" % c
d = "%.4f" % d

l = max(len(a), len(b), len(c), len(d))

for i in [a, b, c, d]:
        print i.rjust(l+2)
```

Which gives:

```
~ $ python test.py 
    4.5656
   24.0900
  698.2300
   -3.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortran io is totally different to C style io in every way.

Go for Brendan's fortranformat package.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortranformat

```
easy_install fortranformat
```

This allows arcane old fortran input files to be created with much less trial and error than trying to use C style string formatting.

Comment: To not knowing the purpose of this answer I also do not know what you find arcane on Fortran formatting. It is pretty similar to C formatting.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm pretty familiar with Fortran formatting. I'm much less familiar with C formatting. I've found this module extremely useful in cases where a legacy program expects input formatted 'just so'. I am able (almost) copy-paste the format statements when using this module. C/F translating a set of statements like 4001 format(i4.4,':',e15.7) 4002 format(i4.4,':',3x,a7,2i5,':',1a4) 4003 format(i4.4,':',1a1) 4004 format(i4.4,':',i5) 4014 format(i4.4,':',2x,A5) 4005 format(60i3)

Comment: If that is a reaction to my comment, you probably didn't get it. Why arcane? And why this answer even exist?

Comment: @VladimirF why 'arcane'? For one knowing Fortran io is a non-transferable skill why should someone have to learn it for an isolated task? As an experiment, try giving the format statements in my comment (and another 30 like them) to someone who is not familiar with both C and fortran style io and asking them to translate them. Afterwards tell them that they could simply have copy pasted them..

Comment: @VladimirF As to why the answer exists. Brendan's answer did not jump out at me when I searched for this topic a while ago. I thought that I would try to highlight the usefulness of this library in order to help other people. I don't have the rep to either upvote or comment on his answer as a brand new user.